# Addition in Dictionaries w/ Lists

Tags: python, list, dictionary

**DRAFT 1:**
I am a beginner programmer and would really appreciate some help on a section of a project I am doing:

```
dict = {
    'l1' : ["a1", 2],
    'l2' : ["a2", 3],
    'l3' : ["a3", 10]
}
```

I would like to sum up the numerical values to a variable
e.g.

```
total = 15
```

Thank you!

**DRAFT 2:**
Thank you for your comments. I will attach the code below:

```
#Ask user how many items are being checked out
item_amount = int(input("How many items will you be checking out?: "))


#Create a dictionary that creates multiple lists for our items for iteration
obj = {}
for i in range(1, item_amount + 1):
    obj['l' + str(i)] = []

#For each item, prompt for name, quantity, unit price
for i in range(1, item_amount + 1):
    print("ITEM {}\n".format(i))
    item_name = input("Item Name: ")
    item_quantity = int(input("Item Quantity: "))
    item_unit_price = float(input("Unit Price: "))
    item_subtotal = item_quantity * item_unit_price
    print('\n')
    obj['l' + str(i)] = [item_name, item_quantity, item_unit_price, item_subtotal]

#Computations
print("Item\tQuantity\tUnit Price ($)\tSubtotal")
for x, y in obj.items():
    for i in range(1, item_amount + 1):
        print(y[i][0]'\t'y[i][1]'\t'y[i][2]'\t'y[i][3])
        print('\n')


#total = 
#sales_tax = 0.8*total
#grand_total = total + sales_tax
```

In regards to my question, I am trying to work out total. Total is the sum of the subtotals

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please include a piece of code that you wrote in order to try and solve this problem

Comment: Try making a variable `sum = 0` and using a `for` loop to iterate over `dict.values()`.

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the
[intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).  
"Show me how to solve this coding problem?" is off-topic for Stack Overflow.
You have to make an honest attempt at the solution, and then ask a *specific* question about your implementation.
Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing tutorials and documentation.
Summing up values in a sequence is covered in many tutorials.

Comment: Gil Pinsky, Thank you, Kindly find the code in my second draft above.

Comment: Prune, thank you very much. I will visit the intro tour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `sum()` built-in method:

```
dct = {
    'l1' : ["a1", 2],
    'l2' : ["a2", 3],
    'l3' : ["a3", 10]
}

print(sum(v for (_, v) in dct.values()))
```

Prints:

```
15
```

Answer (score 0):

For the draft one:
You can simple do:

```
dict = {
    'l1' : ["a1", 2],
    'l2' : ["a2", 3],
    'l3' : ["a3", 10]
}
result =0
for x in dict:
   result+=dict[x][1]
   print (result)
```

to loop through all key values in the dictionary.

For the second draft you can do same the in showing the result in the end and convert numeric values to strings like this:

```
print(obj[x][0]+'\t'+str(obj[x][1])+'\t'+str(obj[x][2])+'\t'+str(obj[x][3]))
        print('\n')
```

So the whole code will be:

```
obj = {}
for i in range(1, item_amount + 1):
    obj['l' + str(i)] = []

#For each item, prompt for name, quantity, unit price
for i in range(1, item_amount + 1):
    print("ITEM {}\n".format(i))
    item_name = input("Item Name: ")
    item_quantity = int(input("Item Quantity: "))
    item_unit_price = float(input("Unit Price: "))
    item_subtotal = item_quantity * item_unit_price
    print('\n')
    obj['l' + str(i)] = [item_name, item_quantity, item_unit_price, item_subtotal]

#Computations
print("Item\tQuantity\tUnit Price ($)\tSubtotal")
for x, y in obj.items():
    for x in obj:
        print(obj[x][0]+'\t'+str(obj[x][1])+'\t'+str(obj[x][2])+'\t'+str(obj[x][3]))
        print('\n')


Hope I helped you. Have a nice time!!!
```